# Link from One GitHub Jupyter Notebook to Another in the Same Repo

Tags: github, markdown, jupyter

Is there any way that I can locally link from one Jupyter notebook to another on GitHub without the need to embed the absolute path, such as https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking/blob/main/notebook1.ipynb?

I create a notebook ([notebook1.ipynb](https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking/blob/main/notebook1.ipynb))

With this content:

```
# This is Notebook 1

* [Link to Notebook 2a](notebook2.ipynb)
* [Link to Notebook 2b](./notebook2.ipynb))
```

I tried two different methods, one using the . for current directory.  Neither worked.

notebook2.ipynb is actually at this URL:

https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking/blob/main/notebook2.ipynb

However, GitHub transforms my link into:

https://notebooks.githubusercontent.com/view/notebook2.ipynb

Which results in a bad link.

If I put this same markdown into README.md it works fine. Just does not seem to like jupyter notebooks.

I would really like to NOT have to prefix everything with https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking/blob/main/, because the local links:

- Work locally, outside of GitHub
- On GitHub are branch agnostic

You can see my attempts to make this work at this short repo:  https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone happens upon this question. GitHub resolved this issue, relative links now appear to work just fine.

Comment: The GitHub 'view' is best thought of as a basic preview at this time. There's a host of issues with it and it isn't their priority to address them all.  
Nbviewer is the Jupyter offering for viewing 'static' renderings that offers a better experience all around: cleaner interface for novices, allows embedded javascript so plotly plots still work, etc.. The relative links work, too as seen [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/jeffheaton/test-linking/blob/main/notebook1.ipynb).

Comment: You can make these links by pasting your URL into [the main nbviewer page](https://nbviewer.org/) and then getting the URL of the page that comes up, or note that you just change the `https://github.com/` part of the URL to your Github page to `https://nbviewer.org/github`. You could then put those links in [markdown here](https://github.com/jeffheaton/test-linking).

Comment: However, links to the same document, with fragment identifier `#some-heading` don't work. It sends me to the directory, not the notebook. It works in .md files though.

Comment: Probably `notebook.ipynb#some-heading` would work.

Comment: The id for the headings is not lowercase in ipynb, like it is in .md. And the links just don't work, even an absolute link with the fragment identifier..